# Which web framework uses 'eservice_enu' as part of its default path?

Tags: url

I've seen `http://example.com/eservice_enu/` all over the place, especially on sites that handle payments. Which framework is this?

I realize any site could choose this path component arbitrarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siebel eService by Siebel Systems (now part of Oracle).

Looks like its an enterprisy CRM/Portal/Asset Management/Kitchen Sink type system.

Comment: Interesting. I see their URI nomenclature is http://example.com/apptype_lang/, where apptype is any number of off-the-shelf applications (in this case, eService), and lang is the language locale (enu likely being US English). Thanks